# What's the idea of Microsoft's "....Abstractions" Nuget packages?

Tags: nuget, .net-5

Can someone explain the general idea behind providing ... Abstraction packages?

As an example, when I search for the word "hosting" in VS NuGet package manager, in the list of findings there are:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstraction
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

Are these all related? Some seem to be platform dependent (AspNetCore) while others are not? Is there a general rule that tells me when to choose which?

Suppose I want to implement BackgroundService in a .NET5 class library, which of these NuGets shall I install? (It seems that *Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions* works fine for me, but I had to try that out.)

Thanks

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` are only relevant if you're running .NET Core 2.1 or older. Starting from . NET Core 3.0, those packages are included in the AspNetCore framework of any Web project or explicitly added with a `FrameworkReference`. The `Microsoft.Extensions.*` on the other hand are still being updated, the latest version being 5.0.0, reflecting the recent launch of .NET 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is that a library or package that you provide would only reference the Abstraction packages for easier compatibility.

E.g. if you ship a company-wide NuGet package with some business logic in it or a custom client, you may want to use `ILogger` / `ILogger<T>` for logging but not actually depend on any implementation for logging (both the built-in loggers or Serilog etc.), so you can reference the logging abstractions for these interfaces.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure that I get it right: I your example, the software that uses my NuGet package would make the decision to also include a concrete implementation of ILogger but my NuGet package doesn't care which one it is because it relies on the abstraction only. But eventually someone needs to reference a concrete implementation, the ..abstraction alone cannot do real work. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. And since it is less likely for there to be breaking changes in the Abstractions, even updating major versions should be easier - e.g. a library depending on logging abstractions 2.1 should still work in .NET 5. without any guarantees though. but these problems previously existed with e.g. log4net.

Comment: Or for DI: Your library may be able to register it's services (singletons, transient dependencies, factories) with an `IServiceCollection`. But the hosting application will need to bring in some DI implementation - be it the very basic but fuctional MS implementation or something more powerful.

Comment: Is there any source from microsoft itself in which we can find these considerations?